# Change a column data type in SQL - blank fields

Tags: sql-server-2008

If I have a column of `nvarchar (50)`:

Suppose 9.99,2,0,4, ,7,9 and I want to change the data column data type.

How can I handle the blank fields so they will be null?

I know that numeric data types cannot stay with those blank fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can UPDATE those empty values to `NULL` as

```
UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName = NULL WHERE ColumnName = '';
```

Then

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN ColumnName NUMERIC(9,2);
```

---

Sample execution with your sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable (col1 nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO testtable (col1) values
('9.99'),
('2'),
('0'),
('4'),
('' ),
('7'),
('9');

SELECT * FROM testtable;

UPDATE testtable SET col1 = NULL WHERE col1 = '';

ALTER TABLE testtable ALTER COLUMN col1 NUMERIC(18,2);
```